# Why does this DATE operator not work on my query?

Tags: mysql, database, web

Can anyone explain to me why during my attempts to select data with a date greater than a specific date it runs the query but I still see dates after 2020-09-01? Due_date is a Date and is stored YYYY-MM-DD on a MySQL DB.

```
Select
        *
    from
        records
    where
        job_id = 13582
        OR job_id = 13583
        OR job_id = 13698
        OR job_id = 13699
        OR job_id = 13700
        OR job_id = 13738
        OR job_id = 14133
        AND due_date NOT IN (
            Select
                due_date
            from
                records
            where
                due_date > date('2020-09-01')
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay careful attention to how you use `AND`s and `OR`s. `And` has higher priority than `OR` does, a bit like how `*` has priority over `+` in arithmetic.

That means that your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  records
WHERE
  job_id = 13582
  OR job_id = 13583
  OR job_id = 13698
  OR job_id = 13699
  OR job_id = 13700
  OR job_id = 13738
  OR (job_id = 14133 AND due_date NOT IN (
    Select
      due_date
    from
      records
    where
      due_date > date('2020-09-01')
    )
  );
```

When what you probably meant is

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  records
WHERE
  (job_id = 13582
  OR job_id = 13583
  OR job_id = 13698
  OR job_id = 13699
  OR job_id = 13700
  OR job_id = 13738
  OR job_id = 14133)
  AND due_date NOT IN (
    Select
      due_date
    from
      records
    where
      due_date > date('2020-09-01')
    );
```

A good way to avoid this is, rather than using so many `OR` statements, use one `IN` statement:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  records
WHERE
  job_id IN (13582, 13583, 13698, 13699, 13700, 13738, 14133)
  AND due_date NOT IN (
    Select
      due_date
    from
      records
    where
      due_date > date('2020-09-01')
    );
```

And an *even better* solution would be

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  records
WHERE
  job_id IN (13582, 13583, 13698, 13699, 13700, 13738, 14133)
  AND due_date <= date('2020-09-01');
```